# How to make image name with post_id wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, imagesource

I have a project to auto make images with each post id
so i have to save each separated image associated with each post and the image name should be post id 
i tried these methods but not succeed

```
wp-content/uploads/2014/<?php the_ID(); ?>.png
```

===================================

```
$id = get_the_ID();
```

then

```
file_put_contents('wp-content/uploads/2014/text-$id.png', $image);
```

so i need a php method to save image with post id in ths line

```
file_put_contents('wp-content/uploads/2014/IMAGENAMEPOSTIDHERE.png', $image);
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$image` is already fine, then just simple use concatenation or use double quotes to use that ID:

```
file_put_contents('wp-content/uploads/2014/text-$id.png', $image);
// you're using single quotes, variables will not be interpolated
```

Either:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
file_put_contents('wp-content/uploads/2014/text-'.$id.'.png', $image);
```

or

```
file_put_contents("wp-content/uploads/2014/text-$id.png", $image);
```

<sub>*Note: Assuming you have proper permissions.*</sub>

Comment: finally , you resolve me a problem , takes more than 25 days of searching